# Solr - Searching through multiple fields with one entry

Tags: solr, search-engine, wildcard

I have the indexed the following fields:

```
example_something_text_en_us
example_otherthing_text_en_us
example_yetanother_text_en_us
```

And want to search through all of them for one value, like this:

```
example_*_text_en_us:"My search text"
```

Solr tells me that it cannot parse the field. Can this be achieved somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you use eDisMax, you could use [aliases](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#Field_aliasing_.2F_renaming), which allow to assign a name that expands to multiple fields. You can also define that alias in the handler's definition in solrconfig.xml, so you don't have to specify it every time in the query string.

Comment: But when using the alias function of *eDisMax*, I'll still have to add each single possibility to the alias definition, right? As far as I understood, aliases don't support wildcards